# Word choice between ''discouraged'' and '' downhearted''; '' insecure'' and '' scared''

Tags: word-difference

I'm writing my statement of purpose, and could someone possibly help me out here? (It may seem a little bit long in length, and I really appreciate your help.)

When I first tried to communicate with him in English, he was **insecure**, uninterested in learning and even **discouraged**.

Relevant Info: The picture I want to describe here is the first time that I met this student, who was a fifth-grader and had learned English as a foreign language for almost 3 years. He is not very interested in English, or say afraid of learning English (maybe because he thought English was boring and those grammar and phrases are hard to internalize.). But he performed well in other subjects like Maths.

At the end of this part, I'd like to describe the change of him in English learning after my tutoring. For example, he becomes more confident and is willing to learn more about English.

So, anyway, about the word choice,'insecure'and 'scared', which one is better here?

About the word choice, 'discourage' and 'downhearted', which one is better here?

Answer (score 2):

> When I first tried to communicate with him in English, he was **insecure**, **uninterested** in learning and even **discouraged**.

*insecure* is fine and would relate to this situation. I would not use *scared* (generally meaning *afraid*), as that would be harsh unless a specific fear was involved.

*uninterested* or *unmotivated* are fine.

*discouraged* is OK. As I read this, *downhearted* is a bit emotional for this context. For example, you might be *downhearted* if you lost your boyfriend.